# how do i bind an object that came from a view to an object that already exists in the database?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to make a login page but my modelstate is coming back as invalid, i assume it's because i'm getting an "incomplete" object back.

here is my controller

```
 public ActionResult Login() 
    {
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Login(User u)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid) 
        {
            {
                var v = entities.Users.Where(a => a.UserName.Equals(u.UserName) && a.Password.Equals(u.Password)).FirstOrDefault();
                if (v != null)
                {
                    Session["LoggedUserID"] = v.UserID.ToString();
                    Session["LoggedUserFullname"] = v.FirstName +" "+ v.LastName;
                    return RedirectToAction("AfterLogin");
                }
            }
        }
        return View(u);
    }
```

here is the `Login` page itself

```
 @model Car_Dealership.Views.Shared.User

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Login";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h2>Login</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm("Login", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
{

    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
    if (@ViewBag.Message != null)
    {
        <div style="border:1px solid red">
            @ViewBag.Message
        </div>
    }
    <div>
        <fieldset>
            <legend>Login</legend>
            <div class="editor-label">
                @Html.LabelFor(u => u.UserName)
            </div>
            <div class="editor-field">
                @Html.TextBoxFor(u => u.UserName)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(u => u.UserName)
            </div>
            <div class="editor-label">
                @Html.LabelFor(u => u.Password)
            </div>
            <div class="editor-field">
                @Html.PasswordFor(u => u.Password)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(u => u.Password)
            </div>

            <input type="submit" value="Login" />
        </fieldset>
    </div>
}

@* This below line is for create javascript section *@

@section Scripts{
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

and here is `User`

```
  namespace Car_Dealership.Views.Shared
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

    public partial class User
    {
        public User()
        {
            this.Orders = new HashSet<Order>();
        }

        [Required]
        public int UserID { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string FirstName { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string LastName { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "User name")]
        public string UserName { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage ="Date Of Birth is Required in YYYY-MM-DD Format")]
        [Display(Name = "Date Of Birth")]
        [RegularExpression(@"/^\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}$/")]
        public System.DateTime DateOfBirth { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string Gender { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Email is Required")]
        [RegularExpression(@"^([a-zA-Z0-9_\-\.]+)@((\[[0-9]{1,3}" +
                            @"\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.)|(([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+\" +
                            @".)+))([a-zA-Z]{2,4}|[0-9]{1,3})(\]?)$",
                            ErrorMessage = "Email is not valid")]
        public string Email { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [StringLength(100, ErrorMessage = "The {0} must be at least {2} characters long.", MinimumLength = 6)]
        [DataType(DataType.Password)]
        public string Password { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string Authorize { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<Order> Orders { get; set; }
    }
```

I've tried making `u` have all the properties of the object it's supposed to correspond to by doing `if(u.username=entities.users.where(a=>a.username)&& the same for password)` but that doesn't work. not really sure what to do here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your assumption is correct: User object that is passed from the client is not full and misses required properties.

**A solution:**

Your Login view should not receive a `User` model instead create a LoginViewModel:

```
public class LoginViewModel
{
   [Required]
   [Display(Name = "User name")]
   public string UserName {get; set;}

   [Required]
   [StringLength(100, ErrorMessage = "The {0} must be at least {2} characters long.", MinimumLength = 6)]
   [DataType(DataType.Password)]
   public string Password {get; set;}
}
```

And your view would be:

```
@model LoginViewModel
@using (Html.BeginForm("Login", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
{

@Html.AntiForgeryToken()
@Html.ValidationSummary(true)
if (@ViewBag.Message != null)
{
    <div style="border:1px solid red">
        @ViewBag.Message
    </div>
}
<div>
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Login</legend>
        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(u => u.UserName)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(u => u.UserName)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(u => u.UserName)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(u => u.Password)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.PasswordFor(u => u.Password)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(u => u.Password)
        </div>

        <input type="submit" value="Login" />
    </fieldset>
</div>
```

}

Controller:

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Login(LoginViewModel u)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid) 
        {
            {
                var v = entities.Users.Where(a => a.UserName.Equals(u.UserName) && a.Password.Equals(u.Password)).FirstOrDefault();
                if (v != null)
                {
                    Session["LoggedUserID"] = v.UserID.ToString();
                    Session["LoggedUserFullname"] = v.FirstName +" "+ v.LastName;
                    return RedirectToAction("AfterLogin");
                }
            }
        }
        return View(u);
    }
```

**P.S.** storing plain passwords is REALLY bad idea. You should store password hashes instead. I would also advise that you take a look at [asp.net identity[1](http://www.asp.net/identity) it really can make user management much easier.